# || (OR) operator in LINQ translated into AND in SQL script

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core

I'm working in a .NET Core project and facing a problem. The table that I'm querying has 2 columns.

- IsDeleted (a nullable boolean column). When an item is deleted on frontend, it will be marked as deleted via this column. It is nullable by design (our former TA did it. I don't want to risk changing it at this moment).
- IsApproved (a boolean column - not null). When an item is approved by administrator, its corresponding value will be set to 1. Otherwise, it'll be 0.

The requirement is any change requested by normal user on the frontend must be approved by administrator. This includes when user requests to delete an item. That means an administrator should be able to see all unapproved items. Furthermore, all items that aren't marked as deleted should also retrieved.

Here is my LINQ query.

```
var query = dbContext.Variations.Where(o => o.IsDeleted != true || !o.IsApproved);
```

When looking at the console of the application, I saw the query was translated like this.

```
SELECT [v].[Id], [v].[Variation], [v].[IsApproved], [v].[IsChange], [v].[IsDeleted], [v].[RequestedEmail], [v].[RequestedUserName], [v].[UpdatedAt], [v].[UpdatedBy]
      FROM [Variation] AS [v]
      WHERE ([v].[IsDeleted] IS NULL OR ([v].[IsDeleted] IS NOT NULL AND ([v].[IsDeleted] = 0))) AND ((([v].[IsDeleted] <> 1) OR [v].[IsDeleted] IS NULL) OR ([v].[IsApproved] = 0))
```

The result is, it only gave me the non-deleted items but not the unapproved items, even though I requested so. If I change the above translated query into this

```
SELECT [v].[Id], [v].[Variation], [v].[IsApproved], [v].[IsChange], [v].[IsDeleted], [v].[RequestedEmail], [v].[RequestedUserName], [v].[UpdatedAt], [v].[UpdatedBy]
      FROM [Variation] AS [v]
      WHERE ([v].[IsDeleted] IS NULL OR ([v].[IsDeleted] IS NOT NULL AND ([v].[IsDeleted] = 0))) OR ((([v].[IsDeleted] <> 1) OR [v].[IsDeleted] IS NULL) OR ([v].[IsApproved] = 0))
```

I'll get both non-deleted and unapproved items as expected. I wonder why the || operator in my LINQ query was translated into AND operator in SQL. Am I missing anything? Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is the `IsDeleted` nullable?

Comment: Yes. That's why I used `o.IsDeleted != true`

Comment: _...must be approved by administrator. This includes when user requests to delete an item_ - That mean that deleted items will always be approved. If so you can use only one condition `o.IsApproved == false`

Comment: Highlight “the change” made to the query. Then *simplify* it to a minimal “valid query”, with the desired logic, and change the LINQ query to reflect. That is: don’t worry about the LINQ generation, and focus on the actual logic - the “AND” is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

ok I've figured out what went wrong. It seems a team member added a model-level entity filter via `HasQueryFilter` method in the configuration class of the entity. That's why no matter what I did, it always generated wrong sql query. My solution is to add `IgnoreQueryFilters` and the problem is solved. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use &&?

```
var query = dbContext.Variations.Where(o => o.IsDeleted != true && o.IsApproved == false);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It gives the different results as the desired OP.

Comment: He said "I'll get both non-deleted and unapproved items as expected". This is same as answered result above.

Comment: I did and it didn't give me any item at all. An item maybe marked as deleted and not-approved at the same time. Furthermore, the requirement is all non-deleted items **and** non-approved items should be retrieved, not just non-deleted or non-approved items.

Comment: see my screenshots. I retrieved 3 items. they are both non-deleted and non-approved.

Comment: && is the one you want. if you get different result, you need to show full codes in your post. your tables or data may be wrong.

Comment: Based on OP requirements "Name5" record should be returned as well

Comment: OP needs to make it clear again. I read his text that OP needs to get all items of both non-deleted and non-approved only. Please make it clear again, OP.

Comment: @Asherguru I've found a solution. Please see my latest answer. Thanks for your help. Sorry I can't share the full code due to the NDA that I signed before joining my company. Even the names of the objects I had to change too. I don't want to get into legal trouble.